# Как устроить асинхронные и обычные методы c#

Tags: c#

При написании приложения не планировались асинхронные задачи, но под конец появилась необходимость поработать с БД асинхронно, теперь получается так, что основная задача заканчивается быстрее чем асинхронный метод, а мне нужно их как-то синхронизировать. Переписать асинхронный метод не вариант, потому что использую асинхронную библиотеку из-за того, что в ней есть все нужные методы работы с БД. Фактически задача выглядит так: разблокировать кнопку на формах после окончания асинхронного void метода.

Метод формы (в нем вызывается `InfluxDatabaseMethods.Init()`)

```cs
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bestAlgNameForDay = logicClass.SearchBestForConc(logicClass.day);
    bestAlgConc.Text = bestAlgNameForDay;
    dataClass.Init();
    InfluxDatabaseMethods.Init();
    buttonOpenGrafana.Enabled = true;
}
```

InfluxDatabaseMethods.Init();

```cs
async public static void Init()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataClass.countOfElements; i++)
    {
        var valMixed = new InfluxDatapoint<InfluxValueField>();
        valMixed.UtcTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        valMixed.MeasurementName = "AlgTwo";
        double temp = logicClass.ValuesLog2[i];
        valMixed.Fields.Add("value", new InfluxValueField(temp));
        var r = await client.PostPointAsync(nameDB, valMixed);
    }
}
```

Получается, что `buttonOpenGrafana.Enabled = true;` выполняется раньше, чем закончится `InfluxDatabaseMethods.Init();`

Comment: `...теперь получается так, что основная задача заканчивается быстрее чем асинхронный метод...` - добавьте код примера в свой вопрос, иначе без примера ответ дать тяжело.

Comment: Есть стандартный костыль  .GetAwaiter().GetResult() превращающий асинхронный в синхронный и грозящий дедлоками.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тип асинхронного метода у вас `void`, а асинхронные методы этого типа ожидать не получится. И ожидание `await` возможно только в `async` методах, поэтому:

1) сделайте обработчик события асинхронным

```csharp
private async void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bestAlgNameForDay = logicClass.SearchBestForConc(logicClass.day);
    bestAlgConc.Text = bestAlgNameForDay;
    dataClass.Init();
    await InfluxDatabaseMethods.InitAsync();
    buttonOpenGrafana.Enabled = true;
}
```

2) дайте асинхронному методу тип `Task`

```cshap
public static async Task InitAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataClass.countOfElements; i++)
    {
        var valMixed = new InfluxDatapoint<InfluxValueField>();
        valMixed.UtcTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        valMixed.MeasurementName = "AlgTwo";
        double temp = logicClass.ValuesLog2[i];
        valMixed.Fields.Add("value", new InfluxValueField(temp));
        var r = await client.PostPointAsync(nameDB, valMixed);
    }
}
```

*Я переименовал метод `Init` в `InitAsync` в соответствии с [рекомендациями](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#important-info-and-advice) Microsoft по именованию асинхронных (awaitable) методов.*

Comment: Поправил код, все отлично работает, спасибо большое!